# Create ListView with InplaceSearch on TeamSite from XML

Tags: 2013, csom, xslt-list-view-web-part

### TL;DR Version

Cant create a webpart with searchbox (`InplaceSearchEnabled`) from XML and even cant modify it afterwards via SSOM to make it work. 
Setting the value over the UI works fine.

Problem only present on TeamSites. 
[image]

---

### Long Version

Possible still unanswered duplicate: 
[View property “InplaceSearchEnabled” in onet.xml ignored](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135586/view-property-inplacesearchenabled-in-onet-xml-ignored)

### Scenario

I'm working with a CSOM XML-based provisioning solution my team created with some Microsoft developers. Sadly we have been and are running against a lot of problems. The problem bringing me here is the following:

### Problem

When adding WebParts to pages like this:

**XML**

```
<!--ignore the $placeholders - they are properly replaced by the solution-->
<Web Title="$Title" Lcid="1031" Template="sts#0" Description="Teamsite" Url="$SubsitePath">
  <TeamPages>
    <TeamPage FileName="Homepage.aspx" HomePage="true" PageLayout="RowWithSidebar">
      <WebParts>
        <webParts Zone="wpz" Index="2" LayoutArea="1">
          <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
            <metaData>
              <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
              <importErrorMessage>Dieses Webpart kann nicht importiert werden.</importErrorMessage>
            </metaData>
            <data>
              <properties>
                <property name="InplaceSearchEnabled" type="bool">True</property>
                <property name="ListUrl" type="string">$RelativeSiteCollectionUrl/Lists/Aufgabenliste</property>
                <property name="ListName">{$listId{Aufgabenliste}}</property>
                <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
                <property name="Title" type="string">meine Aufgaben</property>
                <property name="XmlDefinition" type="string">&lt;View Name="{$listViewIdForView{Aufgabenliste, meine Aufgaben}}" Type="HTML" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="" Url="$RelativeSiteCollectionUrl/SitePages/Homepage.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" &gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;OrderBy xmlns="http://hamburg.de/ProvisioningDefinition.xsd"&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="ID" Ascending="FALSE"/&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;&lt;Where xmlns="http://hamburg.de/ProvisioningDefinition.xsd"&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="DPVerantwortlichkeit"/&gt;&lt;Value Type="Integer"&gt;&lt;UserID Type="Integer"/&gt;&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;ViewFields&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="Modified"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="DPVerantwortlichkeit"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="DPStatus"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="DPF_x00e4_lligkeitsdatum"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="DPKategorie"/&gt;&lt;/ViewFields&gt;&lt;RowLimit Paged="TRUE"&gt;500&lt;/RowLimit&gt;&lt;JSLink&gt;clienttemplates.js&lt;/JSLink&gt;&lt;XslLink Default="TRUE"&gt;main.xsl&lt;/XslLink&gt;&lt;Toolbar Type="Standard"/&gt;&lt;/View&gt;</property>
              </properties>
            </data>
          </webPart>
        </webParts>
      </WebParts>
    </TeamPage>
```

**C#**

```
WebPartDefinition wpdefSharePoint = wpm.ImportWebPart(webPartXml);
var webPart = wpm.AddWebPart(wpdefSharePoint.WebPart, wpe.Zone, wpe.Index);
```

The `InplaceSearchEnabled` property is ignored.

When setting the property over the UI everything is fine.

Since CSOM does not support modifying this property, I made use of an SSOM extension to set the property serverside. 
Sadly the code is only able to remove the searchbox, no matter what I set `InplaceSearchEnabled` to, a modification of the property removes the searchbox (it can be re-enabled via the UI).

**SSOM attempt**

```
internal static bool SetWebPartInplaceSearchEnabled(string serverAbsolutePageUrl, string webPartId, bool inplaceSearchEnabled)
{
    try
    {           
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(serverAbsolutePageUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                var allowUnsafeUpdates = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
                try
                {                          
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    var webPartManager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(serverAbsolutePageUrl, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
                    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart webPart in webPartManager.WebParts)
                    {
                        if (webPart.ID.Equals(webPartId))
                        {
                            XsltListViewWebPart xsltWebPart = webPart as XsltListViewWebPart;
                            xsltWebPart.InplaceSearchEnabled = inplaceSearchEnabled;
                            xsltWebPart.ClientRender = true;                                    

                            webPartManager.SaveChanges(xsltWebPart);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdates;
                }                       
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Logger.LogError(string.Format("SetWebPartInplaceSearchEnabled - Url:'{0}', WebPartId:'{1}' \nError:\n{2}", serverAbsolutePageUrl, webPartId, ex.ToString()));
        return false;
    }
}
```

When decompiling the SP .dll's there is only one reference for `InplaceSearchEnabled`, and it's not looking like it's causing the problem.

```
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared, false)]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.Attribute)]
public bool InplaceSearchEnabled
{
  get
  {
    if (this.SPList != null && this.SPList.Hidden || this.SPList != null && this.SPList.HasExternalDataSource)
      return false;
    if (this.inplaceSearchEnabled.HasValue)
      return this.inplaceSearchEnabled.Value;
    return this.ShowControlDiv;
  }
  set
  {
    this.inplaceSearchEnabled = new bool?(value);
  }
}
```

Currently I'm out of ideas to solve this. Solutions/Workarounds are appreciated.

### Update

Through the awesome [dnSpy](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLgOjwrIvMAhWEeg8KHV-NDz4QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2F0xd4d%2FdnSpy&usg=AFQjCNHM6ysAKHs3hAzl2CFvstISQOU7lA&bvm=bv.119408272,d.ZWU) tool I could debug the SharePoint assemblies. Seems like the getter is the problem.. too bad the `SPList` property isn't accessible.
[image]

### Update 2

I created a test console app to make it easier for everyone to reproduce the error. Here's the code:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts;

   /*
    * I used Microsoft.SharePoint.Client version 15.0.0.0 (I've also tried the 16 version) for the usings
    * Location C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
    * SharePoint Version (via /_vti_pvt/service.cnf) 15.0.0.4693
    * and SharePoint Version (other environment) 15.0.0.4763
    */

namespace Console
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*
                * Steps to reproduce
                * 1. Create a new SiteCollection of type TeamSite
                * 2. Run the code below
            */

            //edit for your url
            var ctx = new ClientContext("https://sp2013base/sites/inplacesearch");

            //here are some XML presets (you need to edit the properties for some of them to match your environment)

            //as simple as it gets
            string shortXml = @"
                <webParts>
                    <webPart xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3"">
                    <metaData>
                        <type name=""Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"" />
                        <importErrorMessage>Dieses Webpart kann nicht importiert werden.</importErrorMessage>
                    </metaData>
                    <data>
                        <properties>
                        <property name=""InplaceSearchEnabled"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                        <property name=""ListUrl"" type=""string"">SitePages</property>
                        </properties>
                    </data>
                    </webPart>
                </webParts>
            ";

            //what sharepoint exports
            string exportedWebPartXml = @"
            <webParts>
                <webPart xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3"">
                <metaData>
                    <type name=""Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"" />
                    <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                </metaData>
                <data>
                    <properties>
                    <property name=""ShowWithSampleData"" type=""bool"">False</property>
                    <property name=""Default"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""NoDefaultStyle"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""CacheXslStorage"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                    <property name=""ViewContentTypeId"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""XmlDefinitionLink"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""ManualRefresh"" type=""bool"">False</property>
                    <property name=""ListUrl"" type=""string"" null=""true"" />
                    <property name=""ListId"" type=""System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"">31e3873d-9bc5-4ba0-961f-1d6db280fabc</property>
                    <property name=""TitleUrl"" type=""string"">/sites/InplaceSearch/SitePages</property>
                    <property name=""EnableOriginalValue"" type=""bool"">False</property>
                    <property name=""Direction"" type=""direction"">NotSet</property>
                    <property name=""ServerRender"" type=""bool"">False</property>
                    <property name=""ViewFlags"" type=""Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewFlags, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"">Html, TabularView, Hidden, Mobile</property>
                    <property name=""AllowConnect"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                    <property name=""ListName"" type=""string"">{31E3873D-9BC5-4BA0-961F-1D6DB280FABC}</property>
                    <property name=""ListDisplayName"" type=""string"" null=""true"" />
                    <property name=""AllowZoneChange"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                    <property name=""ChromeState"" type=""chromestate"">Normal</property>
                    <property name=""DisableSaveAsNewViewButton"" type=""bool"">False</property>
                    <property name=""ViewFlag"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""DataSourceID"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""ExportMode"" type=""exportmode"">All</property>
                    <property name=""AutoRefresh"" type=""bool"">False</property>
                    <property name=""FireInitialRow"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                    <property name=""AllowEdit"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                    <property name=""Description"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""HelpMode"" type=""helpmode"">Modeless</property>
                    <property name=""InplaceSearchEnabled"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                    <property name=""BaseXsltHashKey"" type=""string"" null=""true"" />
                    <property name=""AllowMinimize"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                    <property name=""CacheXslTimeOut"" type=""int"">86400</property>
                    <property name=""ChromeType"" type=""chrometype"">Default</property>
                    <property name=""Xsl"" type=""string"" null=""true"" />
                    <property name=""JSLink"" type=""string"" null=""true"" />
                    <property name=""CatalogIconImageUrl"" type=""string"">/_layouts/15/images/itwp.png?rev=23</property>
                    <property name=""SampleData"" type=""string"" null=""true"" />
                    <property name=""UseSQLDataSourcePaging"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                    <property name=""TitleIconImageUrl"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""PageSize"" type=""int"">-1</property>
                    <property name=""ShowTimelineIfAvailable"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                    <property name=""Width"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""DataFields"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""Hidden"" type=""bool"">False</property>
                    <property name=""Title"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""PageType"" type=""Microsoft.SharePoint.PAGETYPE, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"">PAGE_NORMALVIEW</property>
                    <property name=""DataSourcesString"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""AllowClose"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                    <property name=""InplaceSearchEnabled"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                    <property name=""WebId"" type=""System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</property>
                    <property name=""Height"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""GhostedXslLink"" type=""string"">main.xsl</property>
                    <property name=""DisableViewSelectorMenu"" type=""bool"">False</property>
                    <property name=""DisplayName"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""IsClientRender"" type=""bool"">False</property>
                    <property name=""XmlDefinition"" type=""string"">&lt;View Name=""{BEDB36C4-63B9-43A8-8E1B-DD0CBF298C53}"" MobileView=""TRUE"" Type=""HTML"" Hidden=""TRUE"" DisplayName="""" Url=""/sites/InplaceSearch/SitePages/Home.aspx"" Level=""1"" BaseViewID=""1"" ContentTypeID=""0x"" ToolbarTemplate=""WikiLibraryViewToolBar"" ImageUrl=""/_layouts/15/images/dlicon.png?rev=23"" &gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=""Modified"" Ascending=""FALSE""/&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;ViewFields&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=""DocIcon""/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=""LinkFilename""/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=""Editor""/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=""Modified""/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=""Author""/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=""Created""/&gt;&lt;/ViewFields&gt;&lt;RowLimit Paged=""TRUE""&gt;30&lt;/RowLimit&gt;&lt;JSLink&gt;clienttemplates.js&lt;/JSLink&gt;&lt;XslLink Default=""TRUE""&gt;main.xsl&lt;/XslLink&gt;&lt;Toolbar Type=""Standard""/&gt;&lt;/View&gt;</property>
                    <property name=""InitialAsyncDataFetch"" type=""bool"">False</property>
                    <property name=""AllowHide"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                    <property name=""ParameterBindings"" type=""string"">  &lt;ParameterBinding Name=""dvt_sortdir"" Location=""Postback;Connection""/&gt;
                        &lt;ParameterBinding Name=""dvt_sortfield"" Location=""Postback;Connection""/&gt;
                        &lt;ParameterBinding Name=""dvt_startposition"" Location=""Postback"" DefaultValue=""""/&gt;
                        &lt;ParameterBinding Name=""dvt_firstrow"" Location=""Postback;Connection""/&gt;
                        &lt;ParameterBinding Name=""OpenMenuKeyAccessible"" Location=""Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)"" /&gt;
                        &lt;ParameterBinding Name=""open_menu"" Location=""Resource(wss,open_menu)"" /&gt;
                        &lt;ParameterBinding Name=""select_deselect_all"" Location=""Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)"" /&gt;
                        &lt;ParameterBinding Name=""idPresEnabled"" Location=""Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)"" /&gt; &lt;ParameterBinding Name=""NoAnnouncements"" Location=""Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)"" /&gt;
                        &lt;ParameterBinding Name=""NoAnnouncementsHowTo"" Location=""Resource(core,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)"" /&gt;
                        &lt;ParameterBinding Name=""AddNewAnnouncement"" Location=""Resource(wss,addnewitem)"" /&gt;
                        &lt;ParameterBinding Name=""MoreAnnouncements"" Location=""Resource(wss,moreItemsParen)"" /&gt;</property>
                    <property name=""DataSourceMode"" type=""Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceMode, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"">List</property>
                    <property name=""AutoRefreshInterval"" type=""int"">60</property>
                    <property name=""AsyncRefresh"" type=""bool"">False</property>
                    <property name=""HelpUrl"" type=""string"" />
                    <property name=""MissingAssembly"" type=""string"">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
                    <property name=""XslLink"" type=""string"" null=""true"" />
                    <property name=""SelectParameters"" type=""string"" />
                    </properties>
                </data>
                </webPart>
            </webParts>
            ";

            //from Christoffel de Gruyter's answer
            string webPartXml = @"
                <webParts>
                  <webPart xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3"">
                    <metaData>
                      <type name=""Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"" />
                      <importErrorMessage>Dieses Webpart kann nicht importiert werden.</importErrorMessage>
                    </metaData>
                    <data>
                      <properties>
                        <property name=""InplaceSearchEnabled"" type=""bool"">True</property>
                        <property name=""ListUrl"" type=""string"" null=""true"" />
                        <property name=""ListName"" type=""string"">{31E3873D-9BC5-4BA0-961F-1D6DB280FABC}</property>
                        <property name=""ListId"" type=""System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"">31e3873d-9bc5-4ba0-961f-1d6db280fabc</property>
                        <property name=""ChromeType"" type=""chrometype"">TitleOnly</property>
                        <property name=""Title"" type=""string"">SitePages</property>
                        <property name=""XmlDefinition"" type=""string"">&lt;View Name=""{F52E1EA6-0264-4496-BF96-348EDB8C2353}"" MobileView=""TRUE"" Type=""HTML"" Hidden=""TRUE"" DisplayName="""" Url=""/sites/InplaceSearch/SitePages/Home.aspx"" Level=""1"" BaseViewID=""1"" ContentTypeID=""0x"" ImageUrl=""/_layouts/15/images/dlicon.png?rev=43"" &gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=""FileLeafRef""/&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;ViewFields&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=""DocIcon""/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=""LinkFilename""/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=""Modified""/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=""Editor""/&gt;&lt;/ViewFields&gt;&lt;RowLimit Paged=""TRUE""&gt;30&lt;/RowLimit&gt;&lt;JSLink&gt;clienttemplates.js&lt;/JSLink&gt;&lt;XslLink Default=""TRUE""&gt;main.xsl&lt;/XslLink&gt;&lt;Toolbar Type=""Standard""/&gt;&lt;/View&gt;</property>
                      </properties>
                    </data>
                  </webPart>
                </webParts>
            ";

            //add the webpart to the page
            //change for your environment
            var aspxPage = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/inplacesearch/SitePages/Home.aspx");
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            LimitedWebPartManager wpm = aspxPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);

            WebPartDefinition wpdef = wpm.ImportWebPart(shortXml);
            WebPartDefinition webPart = wpm.AddWebPart(wpdef.WebPart, "Right", 0);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to verify before I take a look, your problem is that creating a carbon copy of the webpart XML in a configured ListView WP is not giving the same result when you deploy it from code? You have already tried extracting the WP XML from a configured WP right?

Comment: @ChristoffeldeGruyter The current WebPart-XML is the result of testing which properties are influencing the result. But to answer your question - the bloated standard XML (exported via _vti_bin/exportwp.aspx) did not yield into success either.

Comment: If I follow your logic, it doesn't seem like your WP is hidden or has an external datasource, so the SPList is probably null, meaning it's unable to pull the referenced list? I'll take a look and see if I get a similar result.

Comment: @ChristoffeldeGruyter If there would be a solution (SSOM or CSOM) to create a preconfigured ListView-WebPart in the described environment, it would suffice to solve my problem. There are few people having the same problem and sadly noone documented his solution. Recently I thought about copying the toolpart's save code (which is not simple if not undoable) or - as the ugliest but possible solution - accessing the HTML and imitating the manual konfiguration.

Comment: @ChristoffeldeGruyter exactly what I thought - dnSpy is backing this. I'll be back tomorrow - your help is appreciated :)

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not seeing this issue, I've just added three webparts through a .webpart file. Two times the flag on True and one time on False and the search bar displays appropriately. I am running SP Online however with CSOM. I will strip the bulk to what you have and try with that. Could you tell me on what type of pages you're looking? Sitepages, views or publishing pages? I guess this being a Teamsite these are sitepages?

Comment: @ChristoffeldeGruyter How did you import the WebPart?   Using the UI works fine for me too. Only when I use Code I have this odd behavior (and the XML-Definition property is ignored there too, but this I have a workarround for). Environment is a content page (Homepage.aspx) in a TeamSite. I recreated the behaviour by creating a vanilla TeamSite and modifying the by default created content page via the CSOM ('WebPartManager.AddWebPart') code and the XML I included above.

Comment: did my answer work?

Comment: @ChristoffeldeGruyter Sadly no - I used a vanilla Wiki-Page to test your code and i even took only your in my test console project. The results were the same. I will provide the exact code snipped I used plus the steps to reproduce it. Did you in any way encountered the error on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

I took your minimal XML, added it programmatically and it seems to work for me.

This is what I used and how I added it.

1. For starters, I used Powershell's PnP library for adding the webpart. You can find it here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell . It's basically a powershell module for facilitating CSOM code. It does the same in the backend as what you're doing.
2. I fixed one parameter in your XML called the "ListName" and renamed it to "ListId". Specifying the type to Guid
3. I changed the properties ListUrl, XmlDefinition, to reflect my environment
4. I added the webpart with this code:

   ```
   $wpXMLMin = '<webParts>
             <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
               <metaData>
                 <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                 <importErrorMessage>Dieses Webpart kann nicht importiert werden.</importErrorMessage>
               </metaData>
               <data>
                 <properties>
                   <property name="InplaceSearchEnabled" type="bool">True</property>
                   <property name="ListUrl" type="string" null="true" />
                   <property name="ListName" type="string">{CC208DDA-51B5-43E6-A5D8-7BAD52850453}</property>
                   <property name="ListId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">cc208dda-51b5-43e6-a5d8-7bad52850453</property>
                   <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
                   <property name="Title" type="string">meine Aufgaben</property>
                   <property name="XmlDefinition" type="string">&lt;View Name="{EC059E86-C732-415F-B315-686368904305}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="" Url="/sites/0002/SitePages/Home.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/dlicon.png?rev=43" &gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef"/&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;ViewFields&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="Modified"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="Editor"/&gt;&lt;/ViewFields&gt;&lt;RowLimit Paged="TRUE"&gt;30&lt;/RowLimit&gt;&lt;JSLink&gt;clienttemplates.js&lt;/JSLink&gt;&lt;XslLink Default="TRUE"&gt;main.xsl&lt;/XslLink&gt;&lt;Toolbar Type="Standard"/&gt;&lt;/View&gt;</property>
                 </properties>
               </data>
             </webPart>
           </webParts>'
   Add-SPOWebPartToWebPartPage -ServerRelativePageUrl "/sites/0002/SitePages/Home_2.aspx" -XML $wpXMLMin -ZoneId "Bottom" -ZoneIndex 1
   ```

With this, it worked for me.

Comment: Btw, I notice now when reading your code, that both your ListName property values are set differently. One is hardcoded and the other dynamic, I have a feeling this is the root cause of your issue.

Comment: That was just my messed up editing. The result was a mix from my testcases (where i use static IDs) and the generic approach. As I dont use this XML in my testcases this can't be the issue. I added my test code, if you want to see yourself.